# Installing Spyder (updated for 2018)

Tags: installation, ubuntu-16.04

I would really like to install Spyder3 for Python 3.6 on Ubuntu 16.04. I don't want Anaconda, I just want Spyder 3.

I've been looking around and all the solutions seem out of date. I have tried the following but no success...

```
sudo apt install spyder3
sudo apt install python3-pyqt4 python3-pyqt5 python3-pyqt5.qtsvg python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit
sudo pip3 install -U spyder
```

The last command gives me this error at the end, which I don't understand:

```
 Can't rollback psutil, nothing uninstalled.
 Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools,tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-479pjggv/psutil/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-i3_5xsal-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-479pjggv/psutil/
```

Any help would be deeply appreciated, I am desperate to install Spyder3, all other IDLEs look far too complicated (I come from an R background).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install Anaconda (anaconda.org) - spyder is included, also almost all packages you'll need

Comment: ok, but I already have Python 2.7 and 3.5 (which are both required by the Ubuntu OS) I think. Does that matter? If I download the latest Anaconda, does it come bundled with another Python distribution? I.e. with Pytho 3.7 according to this link:
https://www.anaconda.com/download/#linux